# How to skip newlines within strings except while writing it to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in the process of figuring out how can I skip any newlines that might be in a string and write that string as a single line while writing it to a file in python3.

Example:

```
stringValue = "This\nis\nmy\nstring"
file = open(filepath, 'a+')
outmessage = "\ntimestamp\nlength\n" + stringValue
file.write(outmessage)
```

- The timestamp, length and the `stringValue` should all be written in 3 separate lines in the file.
- But, `stringValue` is getting written as four separate lines in the file, which is something I don't want.

I tried to give the `newLine` argument while opening a file and specifying the new line character:

```
stringValue = "This\nis\nmy\nstring"
file = open(filepath, 'a+', newline='\r\n')
outmessage = "\r\ntimestamp\r\nlength\r\n" + stringValue
file.write(outmessage)
```

But, this solution does not seem to be working.

I will be needing the newlines to be present in the `stringValue`, so that it can be decoded at a later stage after being read from the file.

Comment: "I will be needing the newlines to be present in the stringValue, so that it can be decoded at a later stage after being read from the file. " Then why not just write them into the file? What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? It sounds like it's actually more about designing the contents of the file, than actually how to write it.

Comment: Try `' '.join(stringValue.split())` to make it a single string with newlines replaced by space characters (or any other character(s) you want).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the newlines with a distinc string that should never appear in actual text.

```
outmessage = "\ntimestamp\nlength\n" + stringValue.replace("\n", "*newline*")
```

Then when you're reading the file, you can replace `*newline*` with `\n` to get back the newlines.

Comment: But that string value will not get decoded correctly after being read from the file later on, if the new lines are removed.

Comment: How is it supposed to be decoded? Do you want to put a literal `\n` in the line?

Comment: So this is a bencoded string, which is coming in with new line characters in it. It is decoded later on after it is read back from the file.

Comment: Yes, I'd want to preserve the format of the string while being written to the file. And it should all be in a single line.

Comment: You can't have a newline in a file and not have it create multiple lines.

Comment: Can the "newline"  option from file.open() help ?

Comment: I don't think so. That tells it to convert `\n` to `\r\n`, which still creates multiple lines.

Comment: You either leave the newlines in the file or take them out. There's no way to write newlines and not create multiple lines, since that's what newlines do. Maybe you should be using a different file format, such as JSON. Or use a database.